# SQL Replace certain rows of a column while also searching for a specific part on the data

Tags: sql, string, replace, sql-update

So let's say I have Table `a_tab` with Column `a_col` that has:

```
AFA
AFB
AFC
BTA
BTB
ATC
```

I am trying to use a replace query that finds rows containing 'F' then replacing them with a different value. In this case, 'Z'.

I tried:

```
Update a_tab
SET a_col=REPLACE('F%', 'F', 'Z')
```

I learned that the three should be `('original','to be replaced','new string')`

my problem is that the query updates the entire row and just the specific part. Need some advice on this.

so my goal is the column above should look like:

```
AZA
AZB
AZC
BTA
BTB
ATC
```

Comment: Put the column name as first argument to REPLACE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the column name as first argument to `REPLACE` :

```
UPDATE a_tab
SET a_col = REPLACE(a_col, 'F', 'Z');
```

Comment: A `WHERE` condition might be wise...